# Copy data from one workbook and paste into another workbook using vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Is there a way to copy one specific cell value from another workbook and paste into another workbook using VBA. So, there are three files here. One file where I am writing the code, and second file where I want to copy and third file where I want to paste.

I am not getting code for this. Can someone please help?

Comment: Hi Praveen, you might want to have a read of [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help improve your question. It should include your current code (whether it runs or not) or at least a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the functions below :

`Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(...)` to open a file/workbook

`Set myWorksheet = myWorkbook.Sheets("abc")` to get the worksheet "abc" of the workbook

`myValue = myWorksheet.Cells(x, y).Value` to get the value of the cell {x, y}

`myWorksheet.Cells(x, y).Value = myValue` to set a value to the cell {x, y}

`myWorkbook.Save()` to save the changes.

`myWorkbook.Close()` to close the workbook.